# Efficient way to process a multidimensional cube

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, sql-server-2014, olap

I am building a multidimensional cube using SSAS, I created the partitions based on a date column, and defined a partition for each day. Source data size is bigger than 2 TB.

While deploying and processing the the cube, if an error occurred all processed partitions are not save and their state still unprocessed.

After searching for a while I found the [following article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/processing-options-and-settings-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017#processing-settings) mentioning that:

> Parallel (Processing option): Used for batch processing. This setting causes Analysis Services to fork off processing tasks to run in parallel inside a single transaction. If there is a failure, the result is a roll-back of all changes.

After searching i found an alternative way to process partitions one-by-one from an SSIS package as mentioned in the following article:

- [Create SQL Server Analysis Services Partitions using AMO](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2796/create-sql-server-analysis-services-partitions-using-amo/)

But the processing time increased more than 400%. Is there is an efficient way to process partitions in parallel without losing all progress when an error occured?

Comment: Have you tried processing single partitions in parallel? From .NET this is easy enough with `Parallel.ForEach`. Getting it all to work with AMO and SSIS may be a bit more challenging due to how AMO manages connections; you need to make sure the commands don't share connections. Generating XMLA yourself and using ADOMD may be simpler.

Comment: This is just the way it is. You have to choose between serial processing where you commit each object as it finishes or parallel processing which is in one transaction (which can roll back on any failure). What error are you getting? Depending on the error there may be workarounds.

Comment: Don’t try Parallel.ForEach. That’s not the way SSAS works. You can’t do two processing transactions on the same database in general in parallel.

Comment: @GregGalloway: in general, no. But are you in fact certain that processing partitions independently can't be done in parallel (from the client side)? I seem to recall those will not be forcibly serialized if you try (but I'm too lazy to set it up and test it at the moment).

Comment: Yes. Certain for Multidimensional you can’t process multiple measure groups or partitions in separate transactions and have it actually run in parallel instead of just queue up. For Tabular it’s a bit more complicated depending on version and exactly what things you are processing in parallel.

Comment: @GregGalloway I think processing partitions in batches will be a good option, please check the answer i provided

Comment: @JeroenMostert why using `Parallel.Foreach` while the user can process partitions in batches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to benefit from parallel processing option then you cannot force to stop the rollback for the all processed partitions.

One of my preferred ways to solve a similar issue is processing partitions in batches; instead of processing all partitions in one operation, you can automate processing each n partition in parallel. (After many experience I found that on my machine configuring the `MaxParallel` option to 10 was optimal solution).

**Then if an error occured, only the current batch will rollback.**

In this answer, I will try to provide a step-by-step guide to automate processing partitions in batches using SSIS.

### Package overview

1. Building dimensions in one batch
2. Get unprocessed partitions count
3. Loop over partitions (read 10 paritions each loop)
4. Process Data
5. Process Indexes

### Package details

#### Creating Variables

First of all we have to add some variables that we will need in our process:

[image]

- intCount, intCurrent: to be used in the forloop container
- p_Cube: The Cube object id
- p_Database: The Analysis Database id
- p_MaxParallel: Number of partitions to be processed in one batch
- p_MeasureGroup: The Measure Group object id
- p_ServerName: Analysis Service Instance name `<Machine Name>\<Instance Name>`
- strProcessData, strProcessDimensions and strProcessIndexes: Used to store XMLA queries related to processing Data, Indexes and dimensions

**All variables that their names starts with `p_` are required and can be added as parameters.**

#### Adding a connection manager for Analysis Services

After adding variables, we have to create a connection manager to connect to the SQL Server Analysis Service Intance:

1. First we have to configure the connection manager manually:

[image]

2. Then we have to assign the Server name and Initial Catalog expression as showed in the image below:

[image]

3. Rename the connection manager to `ssas`:

[image]

#### Processing Dimensions

First, add a Sequence Container to isolate the dimension processing within the package, then add a Script Task and an Analysis Services Processing Task:

[image]

[image]

Open the Script Task and select `p_Database` , `p_MaxParallel` as ReadOnly Variables and `strProcessDimensions` as ReadWrite variable:

[image]

Now, Open the Script editor and use the following code:

*The code is to prepare the XMLA command to process the dimensions, this XMLA query will be used in the Analysis Services Processing Task*

```cs
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices;
#endregion

namespace ST_00ad89f595124fa7bee9beb04b6ad3d9
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        public void Main()
        {
            Server myServer = new Server();

            string ConnStr = Dts.Connections["ssas"].ConnectionString;
            myServer.Connect(ConnStr);

            Database db = myServer.Databases.GetByName(Dts.Variables["p_Database"].Value.ToString());

            int maxparallel = (int)Dts.Variables["p_MaxParallel"].Value;

            var dimensions = db.Dimensions; 

            string strData;

            strData = "<Batch xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine\"> \r\n <Parallel MaxParallel=\"" + maxparallel.ToString() + "\"> \r\n";

            foreach (Dimension dim in dimensions)
            {
             strData +=
             "    <Process xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:ddl2=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2\" xmlns:ddl2_2=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2\" xmlns:ddl100_100=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100\" xmlns:ddl200=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200\" xmlns:ddl200_200=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200\" xmlns:ddl300=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300\" xmlns:ddl300_300=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300\" xmlns:ddl400=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400\" xmlns:ddl400_400=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400\"> \r\n" +
             "     <Object> \r\n" +
             "       <DatabaseID>" + db.ID + "</DatabaseID> \r\n" +
             "       <DimensionID>" + dim.ID + "</DimensionID> \r\n" +
             "     </Object> \r\n" +
             "     <Type>ProcessFull</Type> \r\n" +
             "     <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation> \r\n" +
             "    </Process> \r\n";
            }

            //}

            strData += " </Parallel> \r\n</Batch>";

            Dts.Variables["strProcessDimensions"].Value = strData;
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Now, Open the Analysis Services Processing Task and define any task manually, then Go To expression and assign the `strProcessDimensions` variable to `ProcessingCommands` property:

[image]

#### Get the unprocessed partitions count

In order to loop over partitions in chunks we have first to get the unprocessed partitions count. To do that, you have to add a Script Task. Select `p_Cube`, `p_Database`, `p_MeasureGroup` , `p_ServerName` variables as ReadOnly Variables and `intCount` as ReadWrite variable.

[image]

Inside the Script Editor write the following script:

```cs
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices;
using System.Linq;
#endregion

namespace ST_e3da217e491640eca297900d57f46a85
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            Server myServer = new Server();

            string ConnStr = Dts.Connections["ssas"].ConnectionString;
            myServer.Connect(ConnStr);

            Database db  = myServer.Databases.GetByName(Dts.Variables["p_Database"].Value.ToString());
            Cube objCube = db.Cubes.FindByName(Dts.Variables["p_Cube"].Value.ToString());
            MeasureGroup objMeasureGroup = objCube.MeasureGroups[Dts.Variables["p_MeasureGroup"].Value.ToString()];

            Dts.Variables["intCount"].Value = objMeasureGroup.Partitions.Cast<Partition>().Where(x => x.State != AnalysisState.Processed).Count();

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

#### Process Partitions in chunks

Last step is to create a Forloop container and configure it as shown in the image below:

[image]

- InitExpression: @intCurrent = 0
- EvalExpression: @intCurrent < @intCount
- AssignExpression = @intCurrent + @p_MaxParallel

Inside the For Loop container add a Script Task to prepare XMLA queries and add two  Analysis Services Processing Task as shown in the image below:

[image]

In the Script Task, select `p_Cube`, `p_Database`, `p_MaxParallel`, `p_MeasureGroup` as ReadOnly Variables, and select `strProcessData`, `strProcessIndexes` as ReadWrite Variables.

[image]

In the script editor write the following script:

*The Script is to prepare the XMLA commands needed to process the partitions Data and Indexes separately*

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices;
#endregion

namespace ST_00ad89f595124fa7bee9beb04b6ad3d9
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {


        public void Main()
        {
            Server myServer = new Server();

            string ConnStr = Dts.Connections["ssas"].ConnectionString;
            myServer.Connect(ConnStr);

            Database db = myServer.Databases.GetByName(Dts.Variables["p_Database"].Value.ToString());
            Cube objCube = db.Cubes.FindByName(Dts.Variables["p_Cube"].Value.ToString());
            MeasureGroup objMeasureGroup = objCube.MeasureGroups[Dts.Variables["p_MeasureGroup"].Value.ToString()];
            int maxparallel = (int)Dts.Variables["p_MaxParallel"].Value;


            int intcount = objMeasureGroup.Partitions.Cast<Partition>().Where(x => x.State != AnalysisState.Processed).Count();

            if (intcount > maxparallel)
            {
                intcount = maxparallel;
            }

            var partitions = objMeasureGroup.Partitions.Cast<Partition>().Where(x => x.State != AnalysisState.Processed).OrderBy(y => y.Name).Take(intcount);

            string strData, strIndexes;

            strData = "<Batch xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine\"> \r\n <Parallel MaxParallel=\"" + maxparallel.ToString() + "\"> \r\n";
            strIndexes = "<Batch xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine\"> \r\n <Parallel MaxParallel=\"" + maxparallel.ToString() + "\"> \r\n";

            string SQLConnStr = Dts.Variables["User::p_DatabaseConnection"].Value.ToString();



            foreach (Partition prt in partitions)
            {


                strData +=
                 "    <Process xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:ddl2=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2\" xmlns:ddl2_2=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2\" xmlns:ddl100_100=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100\" xmlns:ddl200=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200\" xmlns:ddl200_200=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200\" xmlns:ddl300=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300\" xmlns:ddl300_300=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300\" xmlns:ddl400=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400\" xmlns:ddl400_400=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400\"> \r\n " +
                 "      <Object> \r\n " +
                 "        <DatabaseID>" + db.Name + "</DatabaseID> \r\n " +
                 "        <CubeID>" + objCube.ID + "</CubeID> \r\n " +
                 "        <MeasureGroupID>" + objMeasureGroup.ID + "</MeasureGroupID> \r\n " +
                 "        <PartitionID>" + prt.ID + "</PartitionID> \r\n " +
                 "      </Object> \r\n " +
                 "      <Type>ProcessData</Type> \r\n " +
                 "      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation> \r\n " +
                 "    </Process> \r\n";

                strIndexes +=
                "    <Process xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:ddl2=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2\" xmlns:ddl2_2=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2\" xmlns:ddl100_100=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100\" xmlns:ddl200=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200\" xmlns:ddl200_200=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200\" xmlns:ddl300=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300\" xmlns:ddl300_300=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300\" xmlns:ddl400=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400\" xmlns:ddl400_400=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400\"> \r\n " +
                "      <Object> \r\n " +
                "        <DatabaseID>" + db.Name + "</DatabaseID> \r\n " +
                "        <CubeID>" + objCube.ID + "</CubeID> \r\n " +
                "        <MeasureGroupID>" + objMeasureGroup.ID + "</MeasureGroupID> \r\n " +
                "        <PartitionID>" + prt.ID + "</PartitionID> \r\n " +
                "      </Object> \r\n " +
                "      <Type>ProcessIndexes</Type> \r\n " +
                "      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation> \r\n " +
                "    </Process> \r\n";



            }

            strData += " </Parallel> \r\n</Batch>";
            strIndexes += " </Parallel> \r\n</Batch>";

            Dts.Variables["strProcessData"].Value = strData;
            Dts.Variables["strProcessIndexes"].Value = strIndexes;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Now Open both Analysis Services Processing Task and define any task manually (just to validate the task). Then Go to expression and assign the `strProcessData` variable to `ProcessingCommands` property in the First Task and `strProcessIndexes` variable to `ProcessingCommands`.

[image]

Now you can execute the package, if an error occurred only the current batch will rollback (10 partitions).

#### Possible improvement

You can add some logging tasks to track the package progress especially if you are dealing with a huge number of partitions.

---

Since it contains helpful details, I posted this answer on my personal Blog:

- [SSAS - Efficient way to process a multidimensional cube](https://data-dev.blogspot.com/2019/07/ssas-efficient-way-to-process.html)

Also I published an article with more details on SQLShack:

- [An efficient approach to process a SSAS multidimensional OLAP cube](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-efficient-approach-to-process-a-ssas-multidimensional-olap-cube/)

Comment: That’s a well described answer. I agree this is a good approach if you can’t stabilize the processing so it succeeds reliably. If you commit in batches the main concern is that users will see inconsistent data after some batches have committed. So either so it off hours or don’t follow this approach.

Comment: @GregGalloway I totally agree with that, the main condition is to run in off hours

Comment: Thanks for giving your time. This method solved the problem without taking any additional time in processing.

Comment: @GregGalloway I forgot to mentioned it. Yes we are running the process during off hours.